# getURL not working for one link (and it worked before)

Tags: html, r, rvest, geturl

I used `getURL` and `htmlTreeParse` to do webscraping with the following code:

```r
library(XML)
library(rvest)
library(httr)
library(RCurl)
url="https://www.restaurants.mcdonalds.fr/"

page = htmlTreeParse(getURL(url),useInternal = TRUE,encoding="utf8")
locs = unlist(xpathApply(page, '//div[@class="department-part"]/ul/li/a', 
   xmlGetAttr,"href"))
```

However, for some reasons, this code no longer works. And in `getURL(url)`, it seems that I can get the whole source code.

```r
url="https://www.restaurants.mcdonalds.fr/"
read_html(url) %>%
html_nodes(xpath='//div[@class="department-part"]/ul/li/a') %>%
  html_text()
```

I also tried `rvest` and it seems that `read_html` doesn't work either. Whereas I am able to view the source code, with Chrome for example.

I also tested another link.

```r
url="https://restaurant.hippopotamus.fr/"
read_html(url) # works
getURL(url) # doesn't work and it did work before
```

How can I try to find a solution?

Comment: I get that the website isn't available from my location (UK). Any other examples you can give?

Comment: @Chris, too bad, you can't look for a McDonald's restaurant in France then. :P Maybe `getURL("https://restaurant.hippopotamus.fr/")` ?

Comment: And `read_html("https://restaurant.hippopotamus.fr/")` from `rvest` works fine.

Comment: _"…As such, any reproduction, representation, use, adaptation, modification, incorporation, translation, commercialization, partial or complete, without the prior written authorization of GIE McDONALD'S FORCE, are prohibited;"_ / https://www.restaurants.mcdonalds.fr/mentions-legales?restaurantId=